# AV Foundation in relation to Camera issue

Tags: swift, swift3, avcapturedevice

I am trying to be able to use a custom camera, and I am converting code from swift 2 to swift 3; I am pretty much complete; but I am getting this error in relation to devices; I want to have a rear and front facing camera and before in swift 2 you would set the devices like so:

```
 let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]
```

now I am using what xcode is telling me to use which is:

```
let devices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition)
```

but i am getting this error

```
cannot convert value of type 'AVCaptureDevice.type' to expected argument type '[AVCaptureDeviceType]'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `deviceTypes` parameter you need to pass in an array of one or more `AVCaptureDeviceType`'s. Your choices are:

- builtInMicrophone
- builtInWideAngleCamera
- builtInTelephotoCamera
- builtInDualCamera

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevicetype) for more information on these constants.

With that said, you are probably looking for something like:

```
let devices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)
```